# How to use couchdb-python to call a view with a list of keys?

Tags: python, couchdb, couchdb-python

I have this `ViewDefinition`:

```
""" Models id."""
models = ViewDefinition('models', 'by_authors', """
function(doc) {
  if (doc.type == "definition") {
    for (var i = 0; i < doc.authors.length; i++) {
      var author = doc.authors[i];
      emit(author, doc._id);
    }
  }
}""")
```

I am calling it like so:

```
models = []
for principal in principals:
    models += [d.value for d in views.models(self._db)[principal].rows]
return list(set(models))
```

How can I ask for a list of keys instead and call it like:

```
models = [d.value for d in views.models(self._db)[*principals].rows]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the solution is quite simple also I had to read the source code to be able to find it.

```
models = [d.value for d in views.models(self._db, keys=principals).rows]
```